# Status update implementation in android

Tags: android

I want to implement status update functionality in android similar to facebook. Please guide me on this, I need to submit my project very soon.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't write the code for you, do you have an issue with a certain part of your code? That we are happy to help with.

Comment: I'm not expecting a code. I just want to know the process or approach I should follow, It will make me easier to code. Hope you got it!